# How do you use input redirection from a file in C?

Tags: c, io-redirection

I'm very beginner-level in coding, C is the only language I have been learning. I've done thorough research on input redirection to a file to try to figure out how it works, but I do not understand where to use the command or exactly how it is used. My question is, where do I put the redirection command line in the program exactly? I know that it looks something like this: ./a < filename.txt , but I have no idea where to put it in the program, or if it even goes in the program? I want to read data from the files into a scanf using a simple loop. Also, the 'a', is that the exact name of the C program you are writing?

Comment: you don't need to put it in the program. in the program just use scanf or whatever input function you want that works from standard input.

Comment: I don't totally understand your question.  What exactly do you want your program to do and what are you trying now?

Comment: Redirection like you describe isn't done by your program.    It is done by your command shell/interpreter.   For example, at a command line, enter `your_executable < filename`.     The precise syntax depends on what shell or command line interpreter you are using.

Comment: Redirection with <, >, and | is something the *shell* does, so it only applies when you invoke a shell from within your program, say, with system(). You could also do it manually with fork() and dup(), etc., but I don't think that's what you have in mind.

Comment: The way you formulated the question I don't see a way to answer it in 10 pages or less :( From your question it would seem that you lack a lot of necessary knowledge to proceed with writing C programs that do file redirection. Sorry. All I can suggest is that you learn the C language (C is not a "program") and familiarize yourself with how the OS deals with "pipes" and what that means for "redirection". Also what are the "standard streams" (input, output, error) of a standard executable...

Comment: I'm trying to fill an array with integers from a text file named array.txt using a while loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to read from a redirection, then the program needs to read from
`stdin`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char line[1024];

    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

    puts(line);

    return 0;
}
```

If you execute the program like this:

```
$ ./readline
```

then the user must enter the text and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If you execute the program like this:

```
$ echo "Hello World" | ./readline
Hello World
$ ./readline < filename
First line of filename
```

then `stdin` will be connected to the pipe / redirection. You don't have to
worry about this, the shell executing the command does the work (connecting `stdin` to the pipes, etc) so that
your program only need to read from `stdin`.

Same thing applies for `stdout`, if you want that the user calls your program
and uses the output in a pipe or redirection, then just write normally to
`stdout`. The shell takes care of connecting `stdout` to the pipe / redirection.

Comment: Execute the program ($ echo "Hello World" | ./readline
Hello World
$ ./readline < filename
First line of filename) As in, this will be at the top of my code?

Comment: @LeyaK sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: it's okay, I think I figured it out! Thank you!