# Getting (null) when passing contents of a text file to main by terminal

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C and I have a problem with passing a simple .txt content to a C program via terminal.

terminal line:

```
./uloh <tests/0000_in.txt
```

0000_in.txt content is just a single digit  "1"

C code (uloh.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Passed digit:\n%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

terminal output:
Passed digit:
(null)

BUT!
if just call

```
./uloh 1
```

then output is just fine. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command

```
./uloh <tests/0000_in.txt
```

does not pass any arguments to `uloh`.  The *shell* will redirect the file `tests/0000_in.txt` as `uloh`'s standard input stream.

See [How do you use input redirection from a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826533/how-do-you-use-input-redirection-from-a-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

`Command line arguments` are passed to the program in an array and you can do what you want with them. In other words `command line args` are prepared before `main` is called. On the other hand `stdin` is an input stream the program has to request data from.

You can feed input to a program from a file if the program reads the argument from stdin.

Eg.

```
int d;
scanf("%d\n", &d);
```

You can't really feed a file via terminal if the value you are trying to pass is from command line argument.

For your particular case, you can try something like this if you want to feed the input from a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int d;
    scanf("%d\n", &d);
    printf("Passed digit:\n%d\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```